# can access the site with curl but not in brower

Tags: docker, raspberry-pi, debian

I have set ghost blog using docker and published the same on the port 6000. I could access the site within the host using cURL http://localhost:6000 and also when I cURL from a different  host cURL http://192.168.178.11:6000 and also cURL http:external-ip:6000
I am getting the following error

```
This site can’t be reached

The webpage at http://192.168.178.22:6000/ might be temporarily down or
it may have moved permanently to a new web address.

 ERR_UNSAFE_PORT
```

All of above options works but when I try accessing the above on the browser none of them works. As always, any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Please provide more info on the way "it doesn't work". You can open up your browser's debugger, see what's under the network tab

Comment: What messages are you getting on your console? Also, have you checked the access logs on your Docker environment?

Comment: Are you running curl on the same machine as your browser or on the Pi? The IP in your error message doesn't match your curl command. Are you collecting to the published port or trying to connect directly to the container ip?

Comment: I feel so dumb..I realized that that I didn't read through the error. The port number where I had published the application was causing problem.the port number 6000 seem to be reserved and is not considered  "safe" . So I changed the port number and it works fine now . Thank you all for your feedback and comments .

Answer (score 0):

The port mapped to the application (port #6000) seem to be reserved and not considered safe. Changed the port number and now could access the application from the browser.

Answer (score 0):

I had the ufw firewall on my raspberry pi and initially I had to enable it and then open up ports that I needed like 9000 for openfire. However after the pi restarted I started facing the same issue where I can use CURL to access the HTTP page on pi from a different machine on the LAN on the same port 9000 but browser calls to page failed. Then I checked the status of ufw and it was inactive. I re-enabled  ufw using `sudo ufw enable` and then all the required ports and HTTP very accessible including VNC